# Rename several files in windows folder with R

Tags: r, dplyr, rename, tidyverse, purrr

I have a folder in windows with 1000 files with *".dts"* format like **20170217.dts** . I want to rename all the file's name and change the year to 2019 , like **20190217.dts**. My aim is properly rename all files in the folder to be able to open them in another software. I tried this:

```
# define file path

filepath <- "C:/my file path/"

myfile_dts_2019 <- list.files(path = filepath , pattern =".dts")

# print
myfile_dts_2019

[1] "20172303.dts" "20172403.dts"


# replace 2017 with 2019
newfiles <- stringr::str_replace(myfile_dts_2019,"2017","2019")

newfiles

[1] "20192303.dts" "20192403.dts"

# try to rename on the folder

file.rename(myfile_dts_2019, newfiles)

[1] TRUE TRUE
```

My script seems working in R, however the original files in the folder still have a name start with *2017*. I am wondering how can I rename them inside the windows folder as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list.files` have default `full.names = FALSE` which means it only returns file name and not the path of the file. To rename the file we need the complete path, add `full.names = TRUE` and then rename.

```
myfile_dts_2019 <- list.files(path = filepath , pattern =".dts", full.names = TRUE)
```